# error in project loading in MPLAB X IDE v4.15

Tags: compiler-errors, loading, mplab, pic32

I am trying to load project on MPLAB X IDE V4.15 written for PIC32MX270F256B on XC32 compiler V1.4 . When I load this project I got this error :-

```
Error: Project "Bus_ClassD" refers to file "app_32MX250F128B.ld" which does not exist in the disk. The project failed to load.
```

I didn't get much detail about this error on google. So, initially I ignore this error and try to compile. On compiling I got this error:-

```
src/../inc/include_files.h:17:30: fatal error: plib.h: No such file or directory
```

So, I installed peripheral libraries.Then on compilation I got this error:-

```
src/usb_host_msd.c:165:0: warning: "STATE_HOLDING" redefined [enabled by default]
     #define STATE_HOLDING                       0x0060      // Holding due to an error
```

I can't figure out the issue. Please suggest me what can be the reasons for these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The peripheral libraries from Microchip are only supporting xc8 and xc16. For the xc32 you need Microchip Harmony. Have you try to find the file "app_32MX250F128B.ld" in your windows folder?

Comment: :- there no file with name "app_32MX250F128B.ld" in my PC

Comment: the app_32MX250F128B.ld is the default linker script file. Try to update your compiler and than search again.

Comment: Still no progress

Comment: I am not really familar with the xc32, but I guess the app_32..... is a custom specific linker script. Have a look in your project folder under linker files. Maybe you could could work with the linker script MC supplied. On my machine your controller works fine with the xc32 1.4

Answer (score 0):

**`#define STATE_HOLDING`** has been redefined. I think it has been defined two times (or more?). As far as I know this causes a compilation error in C.
What's the solution?. Well, I can't "guess" your code, so I can only recommend to add a preprocessor directive. Something like this:

```
#ifndef STATE_HOLDING
#define STATE_HOLDING
```

I hope it helps.